# Interface doesn't recognize equal objects in implementation

Tags: java, generics

I had one interface:

```
 public interface DefaultInterface<T> {
    T doSomething(Integer id, T t);
}
```

And i have one implementation class:

```
 public class Example implements DefaultInterface{

    public ObjectOne doSomething(Integer id, ObjectOne objectOne) {
        return new ObjectOne();
    }
}
```

The Interface doesn't recognize implementation class with equal class in Return and parameter

What is wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Please always include the full error message. Otherwise we have to guess or randomly spot the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell what T is

```
public class Example implements DefaultInterface<ObjectOne> {

    public ObjectOne doSomething(Integer id, ObjectOne objectOne) {
        return new ObjectOne();
    }
}
```